# file_get_contents but no load

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i create a php code to get the first m3u8 link from the tag " hlsUrl " from this page by using file_get_contents but it's not working , any help please

my code is

```
> <?php
> 
> $link =
> "https://stream.live/-/streams/users/kawkaw?includeTrending=true" ;
> 
>    $actualLink = file_get_contents($link);
>      echo $actualLink->find("hlsUrl");
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: `$actualLink` is a string, and a string has no function `find`.

Comment: `file_get_contents` will return string, so there is no `find` method. Parse it first

Comment: Also, for future reference, saying *"but it's not working"* isn't helpful to anyone. Show us error messages.

Comment: not working i mean on the browser show page wont load like a website not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `file_get_contents` will return string JSON. So you need to parse it first.

```
$link = "https://stream.live/-/streams/users/kawkaw?includeTrending=true";
$actualLink = file_get_contents($link);
$actualJson = json_decode($actualLink);
echo $actualJson->trendingStreams[0]->hlsUrl;
```

Comment: thanks now page showing a lot of data , but i need only to show the first m3u8 link taged by "hlsUrl" , any help please !

Comment: @stephanenelson I have actually updated my answer before your comment. Please learn how to parse JSON and access it's elements

Comment: please i need sme help , can you help me to parse only the hlsUrl of the username kawkaw